# page_verify none by default

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, azure

I am reviewing freshly generated scripts out of SSDT publish tools.  These projects were built from a default template, as were the publication profiles.  They set `page_verify none` for the database.

I was under some hazy impression that the best practice would be to have it set to `checksum`.

The only thing I can think of is that the SSDT target platform is Azure.  Can someone clear this up with something authoritative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default options that ssdt chooses often aren't best practices, instead you should choose what you want. For page_verify I agree checksum but it is up to you:

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/setting-your-page-verify-database-option-to-checksum/

Incidentally if you import from a production (or similar environment) and you choose "Import database settings" the actual settings will be imported from the database - if it is a new database I would get your dba's to create an empty one on a dev instance with their standard build etc.

Ed